# Split Postal Code in R ( just the 2 first numbers)

Tags: r, split, character

I have a dataframe. One column is the postal code in Catalonia for example 17190 it's the village Salt when ‘08’ it's Barcelona, ‘17’ it's Girona, ‘25’ it's Lleida and ‘43’ it's Tarragona, the 4 counties.

I would like to know how to split/reduce 17190 to 17, for the grouped by counties

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `substr` for that:

```
substr(17190, start=1, stop=2)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "17"
```

## Edit:

How to apply `substr` to a whole column:

```
substr(c(1234, 4567, 8910), start=1, stop=2)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "12" "45" "89"
```

or with a `data.frame` column:

```
iris$short_species <- substr(iris$Species, start=1, stop=2)
```

Comment: And for apply it to all the column? With the ' apply' function? Sorry I am new at R

Answer (score 0):

Substract is ok and is the way i would do it, moreover if yo have 50 Postal codes you might want to have a second table where you can relation the code to the province name.

Here it is an example that might interest you:

```
Codis<-data.frame(codi=c("08","17","25","43"),
                  provincia=c("Barcelona","Girona","Lleida","Tarragona"))
ex<-data.frame(CP=c("17888","17963","08123","08951","25003","25195","43333","43005"))

ex$provincia<-Codis$provincia[match(unlist(substr(ej$CP,1,2)),Codis$codi)]
```

The result:

```
     CP provincia
1 17888    Girona
2 17963    Girona
3 08123 Barcelona
4 08951 Barcelona
5 25003    Lleida
6 25195    Lleida
7 43333 Tarragona
8 43005 Tarragona
```